# Localhost is showing favicon from another project I run on the same port

Tags: webpack, browser, localhost

As in the title: localhost is showing favicon from another project I run on the same port. I cleared cache and not sure what else can be done to hard refresh it and get rid of it.

Using webpack for development

Comment: Whoever voted to Close this thread - maybe chill a bit? It's not a community-specific question, it's literally browser or code related. Lately this place really got toxic - understand not everyone here knows it all and this questions I couldn't find answer for here.